# SSAS Tabular Model - Size Reduction

Tags: tabular, ssas-tabular

I try to apply some optimization to reduce the overall size of my Tabular model.

In many article, we can find that the best solution is to remove the unnecessary columns and split columns with high cardinality into two or more columns.

I focused on the second hint.

After some change, the size of my data is even bigger and I'm don't know why. I use VertiPaq to analyze metrics.

before change (table size 4463282609 rows)
sar_Retail cardinality 718621 and size 224301336 B

After change
sar_Retail_main cardinality 1663 and size 89264048 B

sar_Retail_fraction cardinality 10001 and size 302518208 B

As you see the total size of new columns need more space ( 167480920 B)

I split column by this statement:

```
,ROUND(sar_Retail, 0) sar_Retail_main
,ROUND(sar_Retail, 4) - ROUND(sar_Retail, 0) sar_Retail_fraction
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you could provide the .vpax outputs from Vertipaq analyzer (before and after column split).

I am not sure which datatypes you are using on Tabular side but if you need to store the numbers with only 4 decimal precision you should definitely go with Currency/Fixed decimal type. It allows excatly 4 decimals and it's internally stored as integer multiplied by 10 000. It saves a lot of space compared to the float data type. You can try to use it without splitting the column and see the impact.

Also I recommend checking how run length encoding works. Pre-sorting the data based on least changing columns can reduce the table size quite a lot. Ofcourse it might slow down the processing time